# Lambda Unable to Assume Role

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3

I am Creating a role for lambda using boto3 for creation of Lambda.
I am able to see the following error:

> botocore.errorfactory.InvalidParameterValueException: An error occurred (InvalidParameterValueException) when calling the CreateFunction operation: The role defined for the function cannot be assumed by Lambda.`

This happens even after adding the Trust policy:

```py
lambda_assume_role_policy={
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "sts:AssumeRole"
            ],
            "Principal": {
                "Service": [
                    "lambda.amazonaws.com"
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

This is passed as :

```py
resp = iam.create_role(
                AssumeRolePolicyDocument=json.dumps(lambda_assume_role_policy),
                RoleName=role_name,
                )
```

The Lambda code is as follows:

```py
response = lambdaInst.create_function(
    FunctionName='Lambda-Func',
    Runtime='python3.8',
    Role=RoleArn,
    Handler='lambda_function.lambda_handler',
    Code={ 'ZipFile': deployment_package, },
    Description=' ',
    Timeout=900,
    MemorySize=128,
    Publish=True,
    PackageType='Zip',
    EphemeralStorage={ 'Size': 1024 }
)
```

And the required Policies are also attached as needed.
How can I resolve this error

Comment: I am also able to retrieve the arn of the role properly

Comment: and my Lambda Creation Looks in this way:

Comment: response = lambdaInst.create_function(
    FunctionName='Lambda-Func,
    Runtime='python3.8',
    Role=RoleArn,
    Handler='lambda_function.lambda_handler',
    Code={
        'ZipFile': deployment_package,
    },
    Description=' ',
    Timeout=900,
    MemorySize=128,
    Publish=True,
    PackageType='Zip',
    EphemeralStorage={
        'Size': 1024
    }
    )

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow - please **edit** the original question with the additional information. Especially Python code in comments is broken.

Comment: I tried to format the code as it should be, where is RoleArn coming from? Are you taking that from the response of the first call?

Comment: Have you considered simply creating the IAM Role in the IAM management console, and referencing it in the configuration of the AWS Lambda function? Or are you specifically wanting to create the IAM Role programmatically?  How are you then attaching the IAM Role to the Lambda function?

Comment: Hi all I am creating a role programmatically

Comment: And I am also able to retrieve the rose's arn as soon as it is created. Still I am facing the same problem

Comment: And there is also a function call that is being designed t9 return the Role's arn as and when it gets created